# Rails make some routes resource singular and some plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to achieve the following paths:

```
PUT        /group(.:format)         api/v1/groups#update {:format=>:json}
DELETE     /group(.:format)         api/v1/groups#destroy {:format=>:json}
GET        /groups(.:format)        api/v1/groups#index {:format=>:json}
GET        /groups/:id(.:format)    api/v1/groups#show {:format=>:json}
```

As you can see I need the PUT and DELETE to be to `group` (no id), but the index and show to be to the `groups` path.

I have tried this on my `routes.rb`:

```
resource :group, only: %i[update destroy]
resources :groups, only: %i[show index]
```

And it seems to create the desired routes:

```
api_group PATCH      /group(.:format)          api/v1/groups#update {:format=>:json}
           PUT        /group(.:format)         api/v1/groups#update {:format=>:json}
           DELETE     /group(.:format)         api/v1/groups#destroy {:format=>:json}
api_groups GET        /groups(.:format)        api/v1/groups#index {:format=>:json}
           GET        /groups/:id(.:format)    api/v1/groups#show {:format=>:json}
```

But then when I run the tests for the show for example I get:

```
Failure/Error: get api_group_path(group.id), headers: auth_headers, as: :json

ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/group.86d95177-9b44-4b5b-8ff7-98b609614c50"
```

So I bet they must be overriding each other because or either the show and index work or the delete and put.

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Can u try the `rake routes` to check again your routes?

Comment: Never tried but may be adding a `GroupController` will help.

Comment: I do have a `GroupsController`

Answer (score 1):

According to your routes for GET request you have to call:

```rb
api_v1_groups_path(group_id) #for SHOW method
api_v1_groups_path           #for INDEX method
```

For PATCH and DELETE requests you have to call:

```rb
api_v1_group_path
```

EDITED: 
Yes, I have checked in sandbox, routes a bit messed up, my suggestion is to replace your current routes with generating custom routes like this:

```rb
namespace :api do
  put "/group",      to: "groups#update",  as: 'update_group'
  delete "/group",   to: "groups#destroy", as: 'destroy_group'
  get "/groups",     to: "groups#index",   as: 'index_groups'
  get "/groups/:id", to: "groups#show",    as: 'show_group'
end
```

it generates same routes as you do have:

```rb
api_update_group   PUT    /api/group(.:format)                                                                     api/groups#update
api_destroy_group DELETE  /api/group(.:format)                                                                     api/groups#destroy
api_index_groups   GET    /api/groups(.:format)                                                                    api/groups#index
api_show_group     GET    /api/groups/:id(.:format)                                                                api/groups#show
```

This should work. I hope it will help you a bit

Comment: The  `api_v1_groups_path(group_id) #for SHOW method` does not work. It goes to the index action. Any idea why?

Comment: How does your current `rake routes` looks like?

Comment: It does work, thank you. But to be honest I think there must exist a better way to not use custom routes.